# Symfony 3 spl_object_hash expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given when submitting form

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am fairly new to Symfony but not to PHP web development in general.  That said I am having a great deal of difficulty getting a "dynamic" form to submit successfully.

I have been following the details on:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data.

I have a `Profile` entity which has a ManyToOne relationship to the `Country` and `Area` entities.  `Area` has a ManyToOne relationship to `Country`.

On the form, the `Area` entity select element is dynamically populated depending on the value of the `Country` select.  This works OK.  Howver when I submit the form I get the following error:

`Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException`.

Looking at the stack trace, this seems to stem from methods to flatten my `Area` entity choice array.

Any and all help is appreciated - I've spent 2 days looking at this so far and I've not got much further!

There are some code details below.  If there is any more information I can provide please ask!

Thanks

**t2t**

---

My `ProfileType` class extends `AbstractType` and contains my `buildForm` routine which builds the form.

Within `ProfileType` `buildForm` I have the following code:

```
    // Location Country & Area
    // Start: Dynamic form stuff
    // http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data
    $builder
        ->add('locationCountry', EntityType::class, [
            'class'       => 'AppBundle:Country',
            'placeholder' => '',
        ]);

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Country $country = null) {

        $arChoices = array();
        if (!is_null($country)) {
            $arChoices = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Area')->findByCountry($country);
        }

        $areas = null === $country ? array() : $arChoices;
        $form->add('locationArea', EntityType::class, [
            'class'       => 'AppBundle:Area',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'choices'     => $areas
        ]);
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // this would be your entity, i.e. Profile
            $data = $event->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getLocationCountry());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('locationCountry')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $country = $event->getForm()->getData();

            // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
            // the parent to the callback functions!
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $country);
        }
    );
    // End: Dynamic form stuff
```

`Country` is defined as:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Country
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Country")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CountryRepository")
 */
class Country
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="visible", type="boolean")
     */
    private $visible;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Country
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set visible
     *
     * @param boolean $visible
     *
     * @return Country
     */
    public function setVisible($visible)
    {
        $this->visible = $visible;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get visible
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getVisible()
    {
        return $this->visible;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

`Area` is defined as:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Area
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Area")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AreaRepository")
 */
class Area
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Country")
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Area
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set country
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Country $country
     *
     * @return Area
     */
    public function setCountry(\AppBundle\Entity\Country $country = null)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Country
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

}
```

And the relevant part of `Profile` is defined as:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Country")
 */
private $locationCountry;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Area")
 */
private $locationArea;

/**
 * Set locationArea
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Area $locationArea
 *
 * @return Profile
 */
public function setLocationArea(\AppBundle\Entity\Area $locationArea = null)
{
    $this->locationArea = $locationArea;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get locationArea
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Area
 */
public function getLocationArea()
{
    return $this->locationArea;
}

/**
 * Set locationCountry
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Country $locationCountry
 *
 * @return Profile
 */
public function setLocationCountry(\AppBundle\Entity\Country $locationCountry = null)
{
    $this->locationCountry = $locationCountry;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get locationCountry
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Country
 */
public function getLocationCountry()
{
    return $this->locationCountry;
}
```

Finally, in my `AreaRepository` I have the following:

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use AppBundle\Entity\Area;

/**
 * AreaRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class AreaRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param $oCountry
     * @return array
     */
    public function findByCountry($oCountry) {

        if (is_null($oCountry)) {
            return array();
        }

        $oRepo = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Area');
        $oQB = $oRepo->createQueryBuilder('a');
        $oQuery = $oQB->where('a.country = :countryId')
            ->setParameter('countryId', $oCountry)
            ->getQuery();

        $arResult = $oQuery->getArrayResult();

        return $arResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error because the id of the object is being passed instead of the object itself for persistence.

Look at your own comment: `$event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)`

So you are passing the id of the object to your `$formModifier` function.

And things fail at this line

`$arChoices = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Area')->findByCountry($country);`

as you pass the id you retrieved to findByCountry.

Bottom line: you are supposed to pass a country object and not just it's id.

Comment: Doh!!  Thanks that seems to have fixed this problem!  Have your answer acceptance with gratitude! t2t